# How can I make one <a> item with its own class a different colour from others?

Tags: html, css

Sorry if my title is not exacting enough. I was not sure how to describe this in a few words for a title.

### Background

I am customising a wordpress.com template.

It's the following site:  http://chaine-charlotte.org/donate/

I have put a gold coloured box (using padding) around the DONATE menu item. But I now have the issue that I need to change the font colour for just that item, both in it's inactive and active state.

I have applied the CSS class .donate to the donate menu item, so I can apply custom css to it.

### What I am trying to do

I have been trying to use Firebug and also Web Developer Tools (Firefox add-on) to identify which selectors I need to modify to change the font colour. I found them, but could not figure out how to **only** change the colours (current and non-current `<a>`) on the DONATE menu item.

As fas as I can tell, the CSS that applies the colour to the current/active menu item across all the menu items is:

```
.main-navigation li.current_page_item > a, .main-navigation li.current-menu-item > a, .main-navigation li.current_page_ancestor > a, .main-navigation li.current-menu-ancestor > a {
color: #C39738;
}
```

And the code affecting the inactive/not-current menu items is:

```
.main-navigation a {
border-bottom: medium none;
color: #FFF;
...
}
```

That one I was able to change by adding in a declaration for `.main-navigation .donate a`.

### Question

So my question is, how do I change this selector so that I have a version of it that only applies to the `.donate` class ?

```
.main-navigation li.current_page_item > a, .main-navigation li.current-menu-item > a, .main-navigation li.current_page_ancestor > a, .main-navigation li.current-menu-ancestor > a {
color: #C39738;
}
```

Comment: Use like this: `.donate { color: red !important; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The donate class is added to the LI element. So you can do this.

If the page or it's child is active, then:

```
.main-navigation li.donate.current_page_item > a, .main-navigation li.donate.current-menu-item > a, .main-navigation li.donate.current_page_ancestor > a, .main-navigation li.donate.current-menu-ancestor > a { 
color: #C39738; 
}
```

If the page is not active:

```
.main-navigation li.donate a {
border-bottom: medium none;
color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Helpful and most comprehensive answer. It came in after I answered my own question, but only by a few minutes, so I am marking yours as **the answer**. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is what was needed...

Add the following selector:

```
.main-navigation li.donate.current_page_item > a, .main-navigation li.donate.current-menu-item > a {
color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the menu id for this:

```
#menu-item-157 > a{color:blue}
```